# GAE Python - Setting memchache gives 'Query is not callable'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I am querying my database for a list of shops, and would like to save this list in memcache as it is re-used on every page and practically doesn't change. The code seems quite straight forward to me but it is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1546, in __call__
return response(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'Query' object is not callable
```

My code is:

```
    shops = memcache.get('shops')
    if shops is not None:
        return shops
    else:
        shops =  Shop.all().filter('active = ', True).order('abbrev')
        memcache.set('shops', shops)
        return shops
```

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Maybe it helps if I explain how I use the output of this. I am then calling the results of this action with Django in the active template, using {{ for shop in shops }}. Maybe I require to declare the "shops" variable again after setting the memchache??

**UPDATE2**

The variable is then passed to the template as follows:

```
    template_values = {
      'shops': shops,
    }
    self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/home.html', template_values))
```

Comment: How do you pass the vars to the template, share that code.

Comment: I've added the code in the second update - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem is coming from the "return shops" call, of which I to be honest don't know the added value. If I rewrite the code like below the error is gone. Is there any way to check if the memcache is actually working?

```
shops = memcache.get('shops')
    if shops is not None:
        shops = memcache.get('shops')
    else:
        allshops =  Shop.all().filter('active = ', True).order('abbrev')
        memcache.set('shops', list(allshops))
        shops = memcache.get('shops')
```

Comment: log some info after memcache.get() and check your logs to see if it succeeded.

Comment: thanks - what I actually meant was to check the content of the memchache. Thinking again with a fresh mind makes me realize immediately that I can just call the memcache somewhere else :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of memaching the actual query object cache the result of the query using:

```
# this will cache the first 50 results
memcache.set('shops', shops.fetch(50))
```

or

```
# this will cache all (not recommended if your set is very big)
memcache.set('shops', list(shops))
```

---

Remove the extra , in the shops

```
template_values = {
  'shops': shops
}
self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/home.html', template_values))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the first option returns the same error, and the second "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

Comment: Thanks for the addition. This didn't change anything and is something that hasn't caused in problems in the past either. I don't understand why it is not working - it seems to be a simple out of the book usage of memchache...

Comment: the error list not callable will be because somewhere else in your code shops is being called, possibly in your template rather than iterating over the list. You really shouldn't be trying to stick callable objects into memcache like a query object.  Which is where you went wrong to begin with.

Comment: Yes you are right, it was being called in the template. To make sure that I understand what you are saying - with the answer that I posted, the problem you are referring to is solved right? Thanks for your help.